# Angular theme with more than 3 colors

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes

I want to make an angular theme with more than three colors (primary, accent, warn) and apply those colors to material elements like progress bars and such.

I was reading this Material design case studies: https://material.io/design/material-studies/rally.html#color

Where they use a palette of 6 colors:

[image: Rally color palette]

To add the extra colors I imagine that making this will be the correct way to go?

```
$mat-extra-color-orange: (
 50  : #fff8e5,
 100 : #ffebb0,
 200 : #ffdc78,
 ...
}
```

But what if I want to use that extra color in, say, `mat-progress-bar` that only accepts `primary/accent/warn`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Angular's Material implements and old Material specification which was much stricter than today. I'd not be surprised if it's simply not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Up to Angular Material 6.x (I don't know what 7.x etc. might change), only the three primary/accent/warn palettes are available within a theme. This is very limiting, but there is one thing you can do that *might* be useful sometimes - define more than one theme.

Extra themes give you extra primary, accent, and warn palettes. You can then apply different themes to different components depending on which primary, accent, and warn colors you want each component to have. (You may need to dig in to Angular Material source code to figure out how to do this, but it's not that complicated - just look at what the [`angular-material-theme` mixin](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6.4.x/src/lib/core/theming/_all-theme.scss) does.)

Obviously, this *doesn't* give you more color options per component, but it does let you use more colors in your application and use alternate colors for selected components. This is sort of against the idea of theming in Material Design, so use cautiously.

For example:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$main-theme: mat-light-theme($mat-purple, $mat-yellow, $mat-red);
$alternate-theme: mat-light-theme($mat-deep-purple, $mat-amber, $mat-red);

@include mat-core-theme($main-theme);
@include mat-autocomplete-theme($main-theme);
@include mat-badge-theme($alternate-theme);
...
```

Comment: Can you point me to a place that shows an example of how to use the above noted angular-material-theme mixin?

Comment: Look in the Angular Material documentation under Guides - Theming. material.angular.io

Answer (score 3):

As of Angular Material 9, you are still limited to 3 colors still. You can achieve more than 3 colors by using multiple themes.

You can generate a color palette using the following generator:

http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5

You'll need a palette per color you want to add.

Then you can create multiple themes to use at once by following their documentation on adding multiple themes:

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes

Answer (score -3):

You can define an alternate theme through this link:

https://alligator.io/angular/angular-material-custom-theme/

Then you can use more than three themes ;)

Comment: *an alternate theme

Comment: Answers that contains only links will be delete in future so please post your answers with code and its explanation.

Comment: dead link, goes to a  404