# Theme colors Material Design vs Angular Material

Tags: angular-material, material-design

If I refer to Material Design guidelines about [Colors](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation), they define :

1. Primary
2. Primary Variant
3. Secondary
4. Secondary Variant
5. Background
6. Surface
7. Error

Angular material define

1. Primary
2. Secondary
3. Warn

In addition the contrast color in angular is the equivalent of the On* in MDC.

1> In Angular Material background and surface are set to white or black depending of the theme builder function. No access for custom.

> **[edit]** (thanks @G. Tranter):
>   Custom background color [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919927/angular-material2-theming-how-to-set-app-background/49434227#49434227)

2> In Angular Material, I can define lighter and darker variant of each of the 3 colors, but I do not have control of where those variants are used !
(unless I manually overwrite each mat-* class...)

I am able to build my theme with two colors (primary and accent). But I don't get the point to define variants if I cannot assign the variants to specific UI elements.

> **[edit]** (thanks @G. Tranter):
>   In Angular Material the use of variants is defined by the component itself.

If I refer to Material design examples (same page linked above) I cannot reproduce the theme with primary, primary variant and secondary for example...

did I miss something ? or does someone can enlighten me about this 2 major restrictions in theming ?

> **[edit]** (thanks @G. Tranter):
>   In Angular Material we can define a second theme (with Primary and Accent colors) that will be applied to a specific CSS class

```
.item-second-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($second-theme);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is actually a restriction (at least completely).

You can customize the foreground and background by modifying the theme before you apply it to your application and to Angular Material. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434227/9226213). However, it is probably not a great idea from a Material Design point of view to use background and foreground palettes that don't follow the guidelines, so there's usually no reason to not use the default ones in Angular Material.

You can't control how Angular Material components use the variants - that is part of the design of the components themselves. But you can control what those variants are when you create your palettes. For example:

```
$primary-palette: mat-palette($mat-blue, 500, 100, 700); // default
```

or

```
$primary-palette: mat-palette($mat-blue, 700, 300, 900); // darker
```

And of course you have complete control within your own components as to how shades are used.

Comment: That is an interesting way to change the background color. My main question was more on "how to use a theme of 3 colors ? " for now I need to specify one theme with primary and accent, then an optional theme with another primary. then wrap the items in a class taging my optional theme... I was just looking for a way to fully use the variants ...

Comment: "Fully use the variants" is an odd statement I think :). Ultimately, it doesn't matter if you use 1 or 100 variants - what matters is that your UI looks good and is consistent (following Material Design helps you achieve this). If you want to try to work with the restrictions of Angular Material's theming mechanism, it is possible ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52394703/9226213)), but you don't have to. All color palettes with all shades are available. You can access them directly, or define your own theming mechanism, or define your own colors. But that's not really Material Design.

Comment: Well, I guess that is steps along the way to adapt from "I do whatever I want with pure HTML" to "I follow a consistent, more sober guideline" I get your point. Material Design is based on 2 colors primary and accent... then still can be extend by defining multiple themes

Comment: It would be nice if Angular Material had an easy way to use more colors (especially for special things like a status icon) - it's not 'forbidden' per se by material design. But they've implemented a fairly basic version of the three color system, so to get past that all we can do is hack it.