# Angular Material form-field outline input color change when the form-field is active

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-forms

Problem Statement:
I am implementing Angular material `mat-form-field` property. I put Form field appearance as a outline. I am trying to change the color of the input border when the input is selected.

Expected Behaviour.
The input field outline border color should change when the input is selected. I want to change the color of the outline into black when the form-field is active.

Current Behavior:
Right now it's showing the angular material default primary color when the form field is active.

[image]

This are all my dependency

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: More information needed, please edit your question. Show *all* code that is involved in these proceedings, not only your package.json

Answer (score 12):

The below CSS should allow you to override the colors.

```
/* default and hover color */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: red;
}

/* focused color */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: green;
}

/* floating label color */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label { 
    color: green; 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the floating label: `.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: green;
}`.

Answer (score 1):

MatFormField uses the theme color property so you can specify the active color as either primary, accent, or warn. The default is primary. For example, to change from the default primary color to the theme's accent color:

```
<mat-form-field color="accent">
```

If using black as the active color is a pattern throughout your application, I suggest you theme your application accordingly and make black either your primary or accent color so that all of the Angular Material components can use it. Instructions on theming can be found [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

If you want to theme just MatFormField across the application, you can create a theme with black as the primary or accent color and apply it only to MatFormField. Then all of the form fields in your application will automatically be colored according to the special theme and will default to whatever primary color that theme specifies. Details can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373852/angular-theme-with-more-than-3-colors/52394703#52394703).

The advantage of using theming to do this is that it will guarantee the result for all aspects of theme coloring and will work with whatever appearance of form field you choose (in case you want to change or use a mix of outline and fill for example). It also allows you to apply the same theme to other components like MatSelect and MatChipList which can be used in MatFormField, and MatAutocomplete which is attached to a MatFormField input, so that the colors of selected items and other theme elements will match the form field theme.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. With this property, when focusing the mat-form-field, the highlighting color becomes the one specified with the "color" attribute.